# "Cannot add/update network before store is read!" when trying to save a WiFi network on Android 9

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I cannot connect to WiFi on Android 9.

This is the error log

```
D/WifiService( 1941): recentFailure: Association Rejection code: 0
D/WifiService( 1941): uid=1000 name=android.uid.system:1000
WifiConfigManager( 1941): Cannot add/update network before store is read!
```

Comment: Based on the source code, [the error message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/master/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiConfigManager.java#1103) was caused by a pending store read, which will happen [on user unlocking/switch, after the user updates from Android N to O while WiFi is disabled](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/master/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiConfigManager.java#296)... (I'm still not sure for the solution)

Comment: how solve .....

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue after an updating of an Android 9 Pie custom ROM.

When trying to configure my wlan, I had error messages:

> **Failed to Save Network**/ Wlan Netzwerk kann nicht gespeichert werden
>
> **Failed to connect to Network** / Netzwerkverbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden

Reset of network / WiFi / Bluetooth functions did not help.

Toggling static and dynamic IP address configuration did not help. WiFi manager did simply not accept and store entered WLAN configuration including password, etc.

Logcat brought up:

```
E WifiConfigManager: Cannot add/update network before store is read!
```

Further research brought up, that since Android 8 Oreo configuration of WiFi is, passwords, SSID, etc of known or configured networks are stored in `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` (previously wpa_supplicant.conf).

Owner is system:system with chmod 0600 privileges.

Checking this file with `vi` brought up garbage as contents in my case.

If the `WifiConfigStore.xml` file is damaged, the described error ensues, that the WifiConfigManager cannot read and update configuration.
Deletion of the file in this case recovers the situation, and Android spawns a new xml template. After a reboot I could enter wireless configuration data and connect.

Note that the config file may also be located in folder `/data/misc_XX/wifi/` on some systems, with `XX` being some combination of two letters.

Comment: This helps understand the issue a little better, but I don't have this WifiConfigStore.xml file in any misc[_xx]/wifi/ directories. Is there anywhere else this file might possibly be?